# font not being rendered correctly by browser after deploy to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, dev-to-production

The font-family my app is using is:

```
font-family: 'Ubuntu', Tahoma, sans-serif;
```

After I deploy (using capistrano) to a server on an Apache webserver, I can access it without errors, but the Ubuntu font is not rendered. Instead, Tahoma is being rendered.

Environment:

- OS: Ubuntu 12.0 LTS
- App Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
- Web Server: Phusion Passenger version 4.0.37
- Rails: Rails 4.0.0
- Ruby: ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-linux]

I'll be happy to provide more information, just tell me what you need.

Comment: is Ubuntu font served as an external file?

Comment: actually, i do not know. In my development machine, which is Windows 7, I do not have a font named 'Ubuntu', but when I included it in the font-family of my CSS file (app\assets\stylesheets\<filename.css.scss>), it shows up in the browser correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line is this is the result of the `ubuntu` font not being a standard font for systems *and* you'll have to include the font-files with dynamic path helpers to get them working in production

---

**Fonts**

As I'm sure you're aware, fonts have to be rendered from files. `Web safe` fonts are ones where all systems have the fonts... but who wants to play it safe!?

`Web fonts` are relatively new, which allows you to render `vectorized` fonts from a series of files. The likes of [FontSquirrel's web fonts generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) or [Google's font library](https://www.google.com/fonts) -- allowing you to include the fonts dynamically

Your `ubuntu` font is a `web font` - you need to package it with your app so it will work cross-platform:

> [Ubuntu's WebFont collection](http://font.ubuntu.com/web/)
>
> You can now use the Ubuntu Font Family as a webfont via the CSS
>   @font-face mechanism, this has been supported since 21 December 2010
>   via the Google Font API. The Google Font API is a cross-browser system
>   that allows visitors to see the clarity and beauty of the Ubuntu Font
>   Family your websites, without having to worry about what fonts they
>   have installed locally.

---

**Paths**

You can either use Google's fonts api to render the fonts, or call them using [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com):

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" %>
```

or

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/fonts.css.scss
@font-face
    font:
        family: 'Ionicons'
        weight: normal
        style: normal
        src: asset_url('layout/fonts/IonIcons/ionicons.eot?v=1.4.1')
        src: asset_url('layout/fonts/IonIcons/ionicons.eot?v=1.4.1#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), asset_url('layout/fonts/IonIcons/ionicons.ttf?v=1.4.1') format('truetype'), asset_url('layout/fonts/IonIcons/ionicons.woff?v=1.4.1') format('woff'), asset_url('layout/fonts/IonIcons/ionicons.svg?v=1.4.1#Ionicons') format('svg')
```

Comment: Hi @Rich, ok I figured out that in my style sheet (app\assets\stylesheets\bootstrap.css.scss), I have this line `@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu);`. If I choose either of the 2 options you gave, my app would still connect to googleapis.com for the font right? What if my app would be set up to be "intranet-only" and wont have access to the net, would option 2 suffice?

Comment: If you're looking for a local-only app, you could just download the [ubuntu font](http://font.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu-font-family-0.80.zip) and use [FontSquirrel's webfonts tool](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to create a series of web fonts, which can be called using the code I used above